# how to change the content of panel when some value selected in dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-3.5, panel

I am using 2 panels in my asp.net 3.5  aspx page, i need to change the content of panel when i dynamically select some value from dropdownlist which is in other panel . Can anybody suggest me how to dynamically change the content of  a panel.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set AutoPostBack=true and OnSelectedItemChanged event on the dropdown. I assume it has runat="server". Then you just write the code that handles OnSelectedItemChanged, that will update the panels

Comment: hi thanks for your reply selection is working now.i am struck in the problem related to panels and dropdownlist. i want to display the content in right side panel when i select the value in ddl in left hand side panel. aligning panels horizontally has become the issue for me. could you please suggest me some alternate solution. thank you